# Spring 3 MVC File Upload and Form Validation without losing the file

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp

Is there a small framework for Spring 3 & JSP that allows server side form validation for forms that contains normal fields and file upload, which is able to "rejecting" the request without loosing the uploaded file?

In more Detail:
I have a HTML Form that contains normal input fields and a file upload field. The validation of this form is done on server side (it is to complex to do it on client side). There is no problem if the form data is correct. 
But the user sends a invalid form then I need to display the form again, the user corrects the input and send the form again. That works fine **except the fact that the user needs to enter (and upload) the file again. -- The solution in general is simple: I need to store the file on server side and then use this already uploaded file if the user sends the corrected data again.** -- But even if it is not so complicated it is a lot of work, and I do not want to reinvent the wheel.

So my question is, is there any small framework that implement this feature, which I can add to my application?

(*At the moment I use: Spring 3.0, JSP, Dojo*)

Comment: why not seperate the file upload and the form validation in 2 different ajax calls? so the file upload field would upload the file straight after user selected the file in as an ajax call, while the 'submit' button will submit the other form fields for validation.

Comment: Furthermore, dojo has dojo.io.iframe for uploading files via ajax, and it Looks like the experimental dojox packages have a dojox.form.FileUploader class that may also help.

Comment: @Dzhu ajax is no real option, because the application should work wihout, so JavaScript and Ajax is only allowed for additional usability function, but the core must work without. -- So one can argument that this upload stuff is an additional function, but it is not. -- anyway thanks for the idea

Comment: Ok then, I don't know of any existing library that takes care of this scenario. but its easy to implement: upon submitting the form (with the file upload) save the file to tmp dir, give it a unique name e.g. use java.util.UUID, save the path in the Session or the spring Model object, let jsp know the UUID of the file and when the form is updated and reposted, the file can be looked up using the UUID file name.

Comment: @Dzhu: and dont forget to delete the file if the user never submits the form or close his session, display the uploaded files in the form and so on... I told that it is not difficult, but it is a lot of work

Comment: lol mate if you think that is too much work, you are in the wrong industry. the files should be written to tmp directory which is automatically purged. see File.createTempFile

Comment: @Dzhu - lol - seams that you need to read a lot of documentation: When are the tempfile deleted? First of all File.createTempFile create only a file in the temp directory but do not delete them, If you use `File.deleteOnExit` then the file is delete on normla VM termination. -- Much to late for an web server.

Comment: @Dzhu let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1905/discussion-between-ralph-and-dzhu)

Comment: Most servers have a cron job that runs every day/wk etc that deletes files from tmp dirs that is older than x hours/days/weeks etc. if you don't have one, then create one. Didn't want to spell out every little detail for you, sorry for not being so clear, but NO i do NOT mean using the deleteOnExit() method.

Comment: @Dzhu: you are right with the cron way Anyway that would be to late for my application (to huge and to many files) -- I need to delete them as soon as possible. When the user session is closed or if the user do not use the form any more (for example 5 minutes after the LAST unsuccessful form submit).

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do is save the file and associate it with the session, and not to rely on automatic or injected validations which would reject the request without allowing you to save the file first - programmatic validation.  Save the file with some kind of association to the session (or the user, if using Spring Security, for example) so it can be used in future requests.

But: that desired solution requires you to establish some offline cleanup of files.  I have a similar situation where a process creates a (permanent) "temp" table.  When the table is created, I kick off a table watcher process annotated with @Async that loops and sleeps the thread for an hour, checking to see if the table still exists (its deleted by the end of the online process).  If the table is still present after an hour, the async thread deletes it and exits.  In your case, you need to establish 1) what to check for to see if the user has completed the process, and 2) how long to check for it.